# Splunk Universal Forwarder as sidecar in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, splunk

I am setting up a splunk universal forwarder as a sidecar with my application through a deployment spec. The splunk universal forwarder is setup as a different docker image where I copy custom inputs.conf and outputs.conf through docker COPY (shown below).

Effectively when I deploy my application, the sidecar is starting. In the current state, the indexer configuration is in the output.conf and which is taking effect.

***The issue comes here: I want to change the indexer server host and port dynamically based on the environment. ***

Here is my dockerfile content of splunk universal forwarder.

```
FROM splunk/universalforwarder:latest

COPY configs/*.conf /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/
```

Built the docker images with name ***splunk-universal-forwarder:demo***
The configs folder have both files inputs.conf and outputs.conf.

The content of outputs.conf is

```
[tcpout]
defaultGroup = default-lb-group

[tcpout:default-lb-group]
server = ${SPLUNK_BASE_HOST}

[tcpout-server://host1:9997]
```

I want to pass the SPLUNK_BASE_HOST environment variable through the sidecar deployment like below.

```
  - name: universalforwarder
        image: splunk-universal-forwarder:demo
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: SPLUNK_START_ARGS
            value: "--accept-license --answer-yes"
          - name: SPLUNK_BASE_HOST
            value: 123.456.789.000:9997
          - name: SPLUNK_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: credentials
                key: splunk.username
          - name: SPLUNK_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: credentials
                key: splunk.password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: container-logs
          mountPath: /var/log/splunk-fwd-myapp
```

I have a separate deployment.yaml per environment (dev, stage, uat, qa, prod) and I should be able to pass different indexer host and port  ***SPLUNK_BASE_HOST*** based on these environments. If I hardcode the indexer host and port in outputs.conf, it will take the same value across all environments but I don't want that to happen.

The environment variable ${SPLUNK_BASE_HOST} in the outputs.conf is not referring to the value supplied in deployment yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an init script that should source the host name from environment variable and update the same in the output.conf using sed command. Finally launch slunk forwarder